# a function that count the odd elements in list with startup pointer START

Tags: c++, list, pointers, count

I need to count the odd numbers in list with startup pointer start

```
struct elem {
    int key; 
    elem *next;

}
 *start = NULL;

// List Function 

void list() {
    if (start)
    {
        cout << "\nList";
        elem *p = start;
        while (p)
        {
            cout << p->key << "\t";
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nEmpty list";
    }
}
```

// Add

```
void add(int n) {
    if (start==NULL || start ->key > n)
    {
        add_b(n);
    }
    else
    {
        elem *p = start;
        while (p->key <= n && p->next)
        {
            p = p->next;
    }
    add_e(n);

    }
}
```

// Driver function

```
int main() {

    int d;

    do
    {
        cin >> d;
        if (d)
        {
            add(d), list();
        }
    } while (d);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know where i need to start my for cycle to count the odd numbers.

Please someone to give me demo or something like that, because i really can't understand how to do it and it will be really helpful

Comment: What do you think `add(d), list();` should actually do? You probably want to return to your textbook.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ with this show me the text of list function like list1 list2 etc.

Comment: @JesperJuhl When i run the program i start typing the numbers and after i click on 0 button i want to show me the count of the odd numbers that i have already typed

Comment: what about to flush the output with a `cout << endl;` at the end of `list()` ?

Comment: @bruno yea its good idea i will do it

Comment: You know how to iterate over the list. Do that, and check if the number is odd or not (the modulo operator could help, or bitwise and), and if it is then increase a counter (that's initialized as zero).

Comment: I put a proposal to count the odd keys, but I also have doubt about _add_, see my answer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i need to do this cycle in main function or add_e ?

Comment: @stamatow `add_e` add a new cell no ? there is no link with to count odd numbers no ? did you read my answer ?

Comment: @bruno yes i do can you show me in demo , to understand more better if its not problem for you

Comment: @stamatow to show what ? how to add an element or to call `nOdds` ? What are your definition of `add_b` and `add_e` ?

Comment: @bruno This is my all code after list function - https://imgur.com/NfgDEgd

Comment: @stamatow so I am right in my answer, `elem *p = start; ...` is useless. _nOdds_ is still ok in my answer

Comment: @bruno In the code that i send you i cut a lot from the original code . Here is the original code . - https://repl.it/@zEmster/Homework2-Solution

Comment: @stamatow I edited my answer look at it

Comment: To count? Why not make a new function `count_odd` that does just that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude show me demo how need to look that function

Comment: @stamatow your new definition of _add_ has no sense , if the user enter 1 2 3 4 only 1 is memorized because of the weird test. I cannot continue like that with you, I prefer to delete my answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you need to write a recursive function for the list that counts odd numbers in the list.

A recursive function can look the following way

```
unsigned int count_odds( struct elem *start )
{
    return start == NULL ? 0 : ( start->key & 1 ) + count_odds( start->next );
}
```

and is called like

```
unsigned int n = count_odds( start );
```

Instead of the function return type `unsigned int` you can also use the type `size_t` that is better.

Comment: I try with your function and that is what i want but nothing is happen i mean the program dosn't show the odd elements numbers when i type 0 to finish the program

Comment: @stamatow Did you include a statement like for example this printf( "The number of odd numbers is %u\n", n ); ?

Comment: @stamatow You included the function definition in a wrong place (it seems inside another function). Check your code.

Comment: i got some answer and say 2 but the real answer needed to be in that sitiation 7 ? maybe something in if statement ?

Comment: @bruno you mean i need to stop with Programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code for counting odd value

```
int count_odd(list)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (current_node = start_of_list until end_of_list)
    {
        if (current_node->value is odd)
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: i copy and paste this but nothing is happen

Comment: @stamatow This is not a copy-paste answer, it's [***pseudocode***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). It show the principle, the algorithm. You have to write your own code.